# Query posts with same or higher meta value and then alphabetically

Tags: php, wordpress

In wordpress, say if I have the following posts with associated meta values like so;

- name = post 1: rating = 1
- name = post 2: rating = 1
- name = post 3: rating = 1
- name = post 4: rating = 2

How can I target post 2 and everything after that, leaving post 1 untouched

I've tried by using the following query with no luck!

```
$my_posts = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'numberposts' => - 1,
    'post_parent' => $parent_id,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'rating',
            'value' => '1',
            'type' => 'numeric',
            'compare' => '>='
        )
        array(
            'key' => 'name',
            'value' => 'post 2',
            'compare' => '>='
        )
    )
));
```

My thinking is to first query all posts with the same rating or higher, but that of course also targets post 1 which sits previously.

So I want to add an additional query that also compares by CHAR from the name meta key targeting everything who's title is or would fall after post 2.

Thanks

Comment: Try rephrasing this? Not sure I follow... Do these have any numeric indexes you can work with? Trying to do `>=` on a string isn't working obviously. Can you filter by rating and then just sort your results?

Comment: No, there's no numeric indexes to work with. Well even if I filter by rating and then sort my results, I still need to compare '>=' from the names. Any ideas how this may be accomplished

Comment: A simple [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) of the returned array (since you return all results anyway). I don't touch WP so no idea how it handles sort of string values there... string, natural, numeric etc...